# Controlled hooks input is not clearing after parent button press

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a search bar in a header component like the picture below. Once you click the search icon the search bar will appear and you can start searching. The idea here, is that once you click the icon again the text inside the search bar should be reset to an empty state. Once the icon in the header component is pressed the `cleanSearch` useEffect will be triggered. inside both console.logs we find that the state of input is set to `''`. However the problem I currently have is that once I show the search bar again the old value is still residing in it. It seems that only the clearing state is not working here.
I also tried to give `<StyledSearch>` a `value={input.value}` and tried different ways to set and clean the state. What is going wrong here?

**edit:** I recreated the problem in this sandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-mahavira-o1hyu

[image]

**controlled input in SearchBar component**

```
/** Search bar in header */
const SearchBar = props => {
  const { isActive, cleanSearch } = props;
  const [input, setInput] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    if (cleanSearch) {
      setInput({});
      props.cleanSearchCallback(false);
    }
    console.log('cleanSearch', input);
  }, [cleanSearch]);

  console.log('cleanSearch outer', input);

  /** controlled search input */
  const handleInputChange = e => {
    setInput({
      ...input,
      [e.currentTarget.name]: e.currentTarget.value,
    });
    props.appbarSearch(...input, e.currentTarget.value);
  };

  return (
    <StyledSearch
      type="search"
      placeholder="Type between 3 ~ 50 characters to find anything"
      isActive={isActive ? 'visible' : 'hidden'}
      name="searchbar"
      onChange={handleInputChange}
    />
  );
};
```

Comment: I can add the parent header component if needed. But i don't think the problem resides there as it only sends a bool value down. `props.cleanSearchCallback(false)` is only responsible for resetting the cleanSearch prop in the parent header component

Comment: put your value in your input tag and clear/reset input bar on your onclick function.

Comment: Fundamentally, you need to tell that component to clear its input, which I don't see anything doing above. But it's hard to be more specific without more context. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder if I would be missing the command the clear the input. What would be that command? I already tried to set `value={input.value}` inside the `<StyledSearch>`

Comment: Just before calling the **props.appbarSearch**. Store the search value in a variable and just change the state i.e input to  ''(empty string) or null and then call your prop function i.e  **props.appbarSearch** with the new variable assigned.

Comment: @PrashantAdhikari Why would I add another value here. The value is already stored and reset in `const [input, setInput] = useState({});`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder see edit: https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-mahavira-o1hyu

Comment: Again: We need a runnable [mcve] to be able to help. It looks like you're trying to use a prop to control clearing the input. Show us how you're doing that.

Comment: @2hTu2 - No, an **on-site** example. [I linked to an article telling you how to do it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/). Questions must be self-contained, not relying on information only held off-site.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder just out of curiosity, what is wrong with using an external free service like Codesandbox. Codesandbox makes reproducing react problems a lot easier.

Comment: @2hTu2 - External links rot, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Well the answer was to add a ref inside the Search bar as seen in the code below (this is the workable example in codesandbox).

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";

const Search = () => {
  const ref = useRef();

  const clearValue = () => {
    if (ref.current) ref.current.value = "";
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input ref={ref} name="search" />
      <button style={{ width: "50px", height: "50px" }} onClick={clearValue} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Search;
```